# GCP - "kubectl rollout restart" results: error: unknown command "restart"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

My GCP kubernetes cluster version is: `Master version 1.15.7-gke.2`

When I run in the cloud shell `kubectl rollout restart`

I am getting the error: `unknown command "restart"`

What might be the reason?

**update**
`kubectl version` resulted: `v1.15.7-gke.2`
`kubectl version --client` resulted: `v1.15.7`

```
fatnj@cloudshell:~ (pop)$ kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.7", GitCommit:"6c143d35bb11d74970e7bc0b6c45b6bfdffc0bd4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-11T12:42:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
fatnj@cloudshell:~ (pop)$ kubectl rollout restart
error: required resource not specified
```

Thanks

Comment: check your kubectl client version with `kubectl version --client`. Does it match server version?

Comment: @HelloWorld thanks. please see my update

Comment: Its weird because `rollout restart` was added in 1.15. Can you add GitCommit hash? or preferably all output of `kubectl version --client` not only version?

Comment: @HelloWorld, added.

Comment: @HelloWorld I added my entire command. it has 1.15.7

Comment: Notice that now you have different error: `error: required resource not specified`. You need to specify name of your deployment e.g. `kubectl rollout restart deployment/nginx`

Comment: @HelloWorld Accepted. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl rollout restart` doesn't work beacuse you client version is `v1.13.11`.
`restart` command was added in 1.15 as states in [changelog for v1.15](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md):

> Create a new kubectl rollout restart command that does a rolling
> restart of a deployment.

You can find [kubernetes client binaries for you server version here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#client-binaries-1).

Download it, unpack and use.

And always try to make sure your server and client versions match.

Comment: That's now a dead link :(

Comment: @IvanixDevon fixed. If they are dead again, look for files named `CHANGELOG-1.xx.md` in the main k8s repo on github.